# Regex to remove all zeroes except the last one

Tags: regex

I'm building an expression that will be processing my fixed width files fields. I need to get rid of all the zeroes in front of the amount, but sometimes there is only zeroes in this field.
There is always 11 characters in this field. This is the expression I have so far.

```
^0+(?=.$)
```

Works fine with `00000000000` as long as there are only zeroes in this field. However this is a payment app and this field stores amounts, so if we get for example `00000000099` it's not working as expected and returns whole string. What would be the best way to approach this? I'm still quite fresh to this, I must be missing a trivial thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which app you are using. Maybe there is a function to remove padding? If you want regex, it looks like you could try:

```
^0+(?=\d+$)
```

And replace with nothing. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJVsT4/1).

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `0+` - Match 1+ zeros upto;
- `(?=\d+$)` - A positive lookahead for 1+ digits before end line character.

---

Or use:

```
^0+(\d+)$
```

And replace by the 1st capture group. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtrLld/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `0+` - Match 1+ zeros upto;
- `(\d+)` - 1st Capture group holding 1+ digits.
- `$` - End line anchor.

Comment: Initial file comes from a bank and it's in a fixed width format, then I feed this into Xceptor and I couldn't find a function to manipulate padding, this is rather a no-code tool, but the first regex works perfectly thank you!